# Save time and date in C++

Tags: c++, date, time

I wrote this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>
#include "TextTable.h"
using namespace std;

int command();
void new_car();
void print();


int c=0;
int c1=0;
char f;
int i=0;
int size1=0;
TextTable t( '-', '|', '*' );
struct car
{
   string car_name;
   string car_owner_name;
   int year;
   string car_paint;
   string car_performance;
   string car_problem;
   int time;

};

car *a = NULL;

car *p;

int main ()
{

  cout<<"welcome to car repair shop program. to help , press h."<<endl;
  command();

}
int command(){
  cout<<"admin@car_repair_shop_program # ";
      cin>>f;
      switch(f)
      {
        case 'n':
        new_car();
        break;
        case 'h':
        cout<<endl<<"help"<<endl<<"p : print"<<endl<<"n : new"<<endl<<"h : help"<<endl<<"q : quit"<<endl;
        command();
        break;
        case 'p':
        print();
        break;
        case 'q':
        char tmp;
        cout<<"Are you sure you want to quit? (y or n): ";
        cin>>tmp;
        switch(tmp){
         case 'y':
          delete [] a;
          delete [] p;
          return 0;
          break;
         case 'n':
          command();
          break;
         default:
          cout << "error! Please try again"<<endl;
          command();
        }
       default:
       cout << "error! Please try again"<<endl;
       command();
      }
}
void new_car()
{
            c++;
            string car_name;
            string car_owner_name;
            int year;
            string car_paint;
            string car_performance;
            string car_problem;
            int time;
            p = new car[++size1];
            if (c==1){
             a = new car [size1-1];
            }
            cout<<"enter car name: ";
            cin>>car_name;
            cout<<endl<<"enter car owner name: ";
            cin>>car_owner_name;
            cout<<endl<<"enter car paint: ";
            cin>>car_paint;
            cout<<endl<<"enter car performance: ";
            cin>>car_performance;
            cout<<endl<<"enter car problem: ";
            cin>>car_problem;
            cout<<endl<<"enter time: ";
            cin>>time;
            cout<<endl<<"enter year: ";
            cin>>year;

             for(int i = 0 ; i < size1-1 ; ++i)
             {
                 p[i].car_name = a[i].car_name;
                 p[i].car_owner_name = a[i].car_owner_name;
                 p[i].car_paint = a[i].car_paint;
                 p[i].car_performance = a[i].car_performance;
                 p[i].car_problem = a[i].car_problem;
                 p[i].time = a[i].time;
                 p[i].year = a[i].year;
              }
            delete [] a;

            a = p;
            a[size1-1].car_name=car_name;
            a[size1-1].car_owner_name=car_owner_name;
            a[size1-1].car_paint=car_paint;
            a[size1-1].car_performance=car_performance;
            a[size1-1].car_problem=car_problem;
            a[size1-1].time=time;
            a[size1-1].year=year;
            cout<<"OK!"<<endl;

            command();
}
void print()
{
    c1++;
    if (c1 == 1){
    t.add( " car name " );
    t.add( " car owner name " );
    t.add( " car paint " );
    t.add( " car performance " );
    t.add( " car problem " );
    t.add( " time " );
    t.add( " year " );
    t.endOfRow();
     }
string tmp;

for (;i<size1;){
     t.add(p[i].car_name);
     t.add(p[i].car_owner_name);
     t.add(p[i].car_paint);
     t.add(p[i].car_performance);
     t.add(p[i].car_problem);
     tmp = to_string(p[i].time);
     t.add(tmp);
     tmp = to_string(p[i].year);
     t.add(tmp);
     t.endOfRow();
     t.setAlignment( i, TextTable::Alignment::LEFT );
     i+=1;
}

    cout << t;
    command();
}
```

But I can not do this part of the project:
"Check what appropriate Data Type provided by the C/C++ library can be used to store time and date information in the program above, and rewrite your program using these tools" I need to get the time and year variables.
The text of the TextTable.h file also contains the following:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#ifdef TEXTTABLE_ENCODE_MULTIBYTE_STRINGS
#include <clocale>
#ifndef TEXTTABLE_USE_EN_US_UTF8
#define TEXTTABLE_USE_EN_US_UTF8
#endif
#endif

class TextTable {

    public:
    enum class Alignment { LEFT, RIGHT };
    typedef std::vector< std::string > Row;
    TextTable() :
        _horizontal( '-' ),
        _vertical( '|' ),
        _corner( '+' ),
        _has_ruler(true)
    {}

    TextTable( char horizontal, char vertical, char corner ) :
        _horizontal( horizontal ),
        _vertical( vertical ),
        _corner( corner ),
        _has_ruler(true)
    {}

    explicit TextTable( char vertical ) :
        _horizontal( '\0' ),
        _vertical( vertical ),
        _corner( '\0' ),
        _has_ruler( false )
    {}

    void setAlignment( unsigned i, Alignment alignment )
    {
        _alignment[ i ] = alignment;
    }

    Alignment alignment( unsigned i ) const
    { return _alignment[ i ]; }

    char vertical() const
    { return _vertical; }

    char horizontal() const
    { return _horizontal; }

    void add( std::string const & content )
    {
        _current.push_back( content );
    }

    void endOfRow()
    {
        _rows.push_back( _current );
        _current.assign( 0, "" );
    }

    template <typename Iterator>
    void addRow( Iterator begin, Iterator end )
    {
        for( auto i = begin; i != end; ++i ) {
           add( * i );
        }
        endOfRow();
    }

    template <typename Container>
    void addRow( Container const & container )
    {
        addRow( container.begin(), container.end() );
    }

    std::vector< Row > const & rows() const
    {
        return _rows;
    }

    void setup() const
    {
        determineWidths();
        setupAlignment();
    }

    std::string ruler() const
    {
        std::string result;
        result += _corner;
        for( auto width = _width.begin(); width != _width.end(); ++ width ) {
            result += repeat( * width, _horizontal );
            result += _corner;
        }

        return result;
    }

    int width( unsigned i ) const
    { return _width[ i ]; }

    bool has_ruler() const { return _has_ruler;}

    int correctDistance(std::string string_to_correct) const
        {
            return static_cast<int>(string_to_correct.size()) - static_cast<int>(glyphLength(string_to_correct));
        };

    private:
    const char _horizontal;
    const char _vertical;
    const char _corner;
    const bool _has_ruler;
    Row _current;
    std::vector< Row > _rows;
    std::vector< unsigned > mutable _width;
    std::vector< unsigned > mutable _utf8width;
    std::map< unsigned, Alignment > mutable _alignment;

    static std::string repeat( unsigned times, char c )
    {
        std::string result;
        for( ; times > 0; -- times )
            result += c;

        return result;
    }

    unsigned columns() const
    {
        return _rows[ 0 ].size();
    }

    unsigned glyphLength( std::string s ) const
    {
        unsigned int _byteLength = s.length();
#ifdef TEXTTABLE_ENCODE_MULTIBYTE_STRINGS
#ifdef TEXTTABLE_USE_EN_US_UTF8
        std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
#else
#error You need to specify the encoding if the TextTable library uses multybyte string encoding!
#endif
        unsigned int u = 0;
        const char *c_str = s.c_str();
        unsigned _glyphLength = 0;
        while(u < _byteLength)
        {
            u += std::mblen(&c_str[u], _byteLength - u);
            _glyphLength += 1;
        }
        return _glyphLength;
#else
        return _byteLength;
#endif
    }

    void determineWidths() const
    {
        _width.assign( columns(), 0 );
        _utf8width.assign( columns(), 0 );
        for ( auto rowIterator = _rows.begin(); rowIterator != _rows.end(); ++ rowIterator ) {
            Row const & row = * rowIterator;
            for ( unsigned i = 0; i < row.size(); ++i ) {
                _width[ i ] = _width[ i ] > glyphLength(row[ i ]) ? _width[ i ] : glyphLength(row[ i ]);
            }
        }
    }

    void setupAlignment() const
    {
        for ( unsigned i = 0; i < columns(); ++i ) {
            if ( _alignment.find( i ) == _alignment.end() ) {
                _alignment[ i ] = Alignment::LEFT;
            }
        }
    }
};

inline std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & stream, TextTable const & table )
{
    table.setup();
    if (table.has_ruler()) {
        stream << table.ruler() << "\n";
    }
    for ( auto rowIterator = table.rows().begin(); rowIterator != table.rows().end(); ++ rowIterator ) {
        TextTable::Row const & row = * rowIterator;
        stream << table.vertical();
        for ( unsigned i = 0; i < row.size(); ++i ) {
            auto alignment = table.alignment( i ) == TextTable::Alignment::LEFT ? std::left : std::right;
            // std::setw( width ) works as follows: a string which goes in the stream with byte length (!) l is filled with n spaces so that l+n=width.
            // For a utf8 encoded string the glyph length g might be smaller than l. We need n spaces so that g+n=width which is equivalent to g+n+l-l=width ==> l+n = width+l-g
            // l-g (that means glyph length minus byte length) has to be added to the width argument.
            // l-g is computed by correctDistance.
            stream << std::setw( table.width( i ) + table.correctDistance(row[ i ])) << alignment << row[ i ];
            stream << table.vertical();
        }
        stream << "\n";
        if (table.has_ruler()) {
            stream << table.ruler() << "\n";
        }
    }

    return stream;
}
```

What appropriate Data Type provided by the C/C++ library can be used?

Comment: [Date and time utilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)?

Comment: Are you asking "what appropriate Data Type provided by the C/C++ library can be used"?  Or are you asking how to "rewrite your program using these tools"?

Comment: what appropriate Data Type provided by the C/C++ library can be used

Comment: For example, print :
Enter the time:
And input to a clock such as 10:00 and save it in a data type.

Comment: Just saving it is meaningless. What do you intend to later do with the stored time and date? Just output it? You can use an array of `char`. But if you want to do more complicated things, like determining the number of days since then to today, things get more complicated.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but I'm taking c++ training and the course project has said to use a suitable data type.

Comment: @SMARTNIMA your question asks for an "appropriate" data type.  _appropriate for what_?  A correct answer (and the complexity of the answer) depends heavily on what it should be appropriate for.  Printing?  Sorting?  Incrementing?  This may be a question that you need to ask of the person who gave you this project.

Comment: If your training literally uses the term "the C/C++ library", then you should be aware that this is almost certainly not a very good training. C and C++ are two distinct languages. On Linux, for instance, you'll find `libc` and `llibstc++`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look up `std::time` on a site like http://www.cppreference.com. There is a lot of information there.